# Sanity Check an MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Is there any way to quickly test whether an `MKCoordinateRegion` is good or not? I've swapped  latitude for longitude and caused an application crash. I'd like to be able to see whether it's possible to perform a `setRegion` before I actually do it. Will `MKCoordinateRegionMake` test the values I give it?

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to clarify "mixed up". Did you swap latitude and longitude values or did you put in values that were out of range?

Comment: I swapped them, but I'd really like to check for any problems before I plug the values into `setRegion`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out I had swapped my latitude and longitude somewhere. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
// check for sane span values
if (currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta <= 0.0f || currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta <= 0.0f) {
    currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 1.0f;
    currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 1.0f;
}
// check for sane center values
if (currentRegion.center.latitude > 90.0f || currentRegion.center.latitude < -90.0f ||
    currentRegion.center.longitude > 180.0f || currentRegion.center.longitude < -180.0f
    ) {
    // Take me to Tokyo.
    currentRegion.center.latitude = 35.4f;
    currentRegion.center.longitude = 139.4f;
}
```

Comment: you might also want to check if `currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta` or `currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta` is bigger than `360.0f`

Answer (score -1):

I haven't fiddle with the map much so take this with a grain of salt.

It sounds like you need to put a range check on your values for latitude, longitude and span before you use them. <strike>Latitude and longitude should in all cases have values between -180 and 180.</strike>

### Edit01:

<strike>I don't think that swapping latitude and longitude could cause a crash. They both have exactly the same units (degrees) and ranges(-180-->180). All valid values of latitude are also valid values for longitude and vice versa. For this reason, MKCoordinateRegionMake won't be able to tell that you've swapped the values because they would still be valid coordinates, just not anywhere near where you wanted.</strike>

I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit. The maximum value for longitude is 180°, but for latitude it's only 90°. I had swapped them somewhere else in the code, but your answer gave me a hint about the code to write.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

Comment: Dang, I knew that! Somewhere my old scout master is rolling over in his grave. Weird how you get stuck on an idea even though you know better. Of course, this does explain why I hit the iceberg.